# How do I know which shared folders file have moved under windows server 2008?

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, monitoring, file-sharing

I have Windows 2008 domain controller. I also use this server for users' shared folders.

I'd like to know the users shared folder files movement on the server side. For example, when someone moves one folder/file from one shared folder to another, I need to see a log.

Is there a default tool inside Windows 2008 for this? Or is there any 3rd party tools?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of popular options that haven't been mentioned by others are [OSSEC](http://www.ossec.net) and [Verisys](http://www.ionx.co.uk).

[OSSEC](http://www.ossec.net) is an Open Source system that can monitor filesystems for changes. It's certainly not the slickest in terms of ease of use, but it is free, and works on Windows and Linux.

[Ionx Verisys](http://www.ionx.co.uk) is a commercial file integrity monitoring system. This is *much* easier to use than OSSEC, or Tripwire (which someone else already mentioned), and isn't that expensive compared to other commercial alternatives (e.g Tripwire). Though it's more expensive than OSSEC, of course :)

P.S. You might want to work on that 0% accept rate a bit!

Answer (score 0):

The built-in auditing will do what you want, after you enable and configure it. But it's hellish to read the logs and extract useful info.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few products that can help with this:

Power Admin's PA File Sight

ScriptLogic's File Audit

ISDecisions's FileAuditor

Answer (score -1):

Yes try tripwire more compliance network security tool, but does exactly what you want